# CentOS7 user not inheriting group permissions

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos, file-permissions

I've been following the tutorial at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-centos-7 (along with all the prereq tutorials) to setup wordpress on my new CentOS7 server. Everything is working fine up to this point

`sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/*`

I understand that the above command assigns ownership to the apache user and group. Normally, though, I connect through putty and Filezilla using my own `myuser` account, and would like to enable permissions for that account.

So in addition to the above command, I've also added `myuser` to the `apache` group and logged out and logged back in, however I still get permission denied error messages when I try to perform CRUD operations in the html folder. However, if I elevate the commands with `sudo` they work, so I'm a bit stumped as to how to permit the `myuser` account to perform file operations. Any ideas?

Comment: Be noted that owner permission and group permission are independent. For example, if the file has permision of 644. The user `apache` can write to the file but users in the `apache` group can only read.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to check both ownership, permissions, and selinux contexts

Ownership - Sounds like you've got this right.  Owner:Group on CentOS7 should be apache:apache.  For your user you will have to add apache as a supplementary group.  You can check this with `id myuser`, if apache does not show up in the list of groups, then run `usermod -a -G apache myuser`.

Permissions - They're listed as rwxrwxrwx.  the middle set of rwx is the important part as it controls access via group (so is what matters for myuser).  You will probably only need read/write permissions so a `chmod -R 664 directoryname` would probably suffice (read/write for apache user and group, read-only for everyone else).  You can check the permissions with `ls -l`.

Note: WordPress usually contains a hidden '.htaccess' file, you will need to manually apply the chmod to that, and any other hidden file, as recursive chmod / chown will skip them.

SELinux contexts - These you can check with `ls -Z`.  To turn off SELinux enforcement you can run `setenforce 0` - This is good for debugging whether SELinux is the culprit or not, however you should turn it back on when done testing using `setenforce 1`.  If SELinux is the problem, then likely what you'll need to do is change the context of the files with something along the lines of `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t directoryname`

Note: A recursive chcon will also skip hidden files (any file that starts with a '.')

Side-Note:  If you are using symlinks, you should make sure both the linked directory and the actual symlink itself have the appropriate ownership / permissions.  To target a symlink with chmod / chown, use the `-h` flag and, if targeting a directory, make sure the trailing slash is not present (eg. `/var/www/html/linked_dir` and not `/var/www/html/linked_dir/` - be careful if using tab-completion as it will automatically add the trailing slash)